# how to get the control of the button in class file in .java file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just want to get the control of delete checkbutton in delete wizard of eclipse,which is declared in .class file of eclipse(`DeleteResourceWizard.class`), so that i can set the delete option of the project .I am facing the problem  like even if i check the delete button -it get changed to false option while handling in .java file...by default it is set as false.How to handle this...

code in .class file

```
private static class DeleteResourcesRefactoringConfigurationPage extends UserInputWizardPage {             

    private DeleteResourcesProcessor fRefactoringProcessor;
    private Button fDeleteButton;

    public DeleteResourcesRefactoringConfigurationPage(DeleteResourcesProcessor processor) {
        super("DeleteResourcesRefactoringConfigurationPage"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        fRefactoringProcessor= processor;
    }
```

i need to get the control of this fDeleteButton-to delete the project completely from the disk,first is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to define your own handler for the `org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.commands.deleteResources` command which invokes this wizard. The normal handler `org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.DeleteResourcesHandler` is just a default handler so it can be overridden. You would then have to use your own handler, wizard and wizard page (none of which are very long).